# Can't Build My Warframe

Tags: warframe

I bought a couple of *Warframe* blueprints, and one of them is Vauban. I want to get ready to build it, but it is not showing the separate pieces for what I have to build; first it shows the Vauban helmet, then the chassis and systems, but it's just showing the blueprint and everything i have to build for Vauban. Beside it, I do have a lot of other blueprints; is my inventory just full?

Answer (score 6):

To build a warframe, you need the blueprint + the 3 required parts (system, helmet, chassis).

Typically, you can by the blueprint with credits from the store. For the parts, you have to fight bosses (they drop the parts).

Vauban parts can only be acquired from alert missions.

When you get warframe parts, go into the forge and craft them (each part takes credits+resources+time). Once all 3 parts are finished, you can start crafting the actual warframe.

On the [warframe wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Warframes) you can check where to get the parts for a frame.

It's also possible to buy a complete frame from the market with platinum.

Regarding your invenotry: There are different inventory sections and only 2 are limited by space - Weapons and Warframes. You can buy more space with platinum.

Comment: Since this was bumped to the front page, I'm going to note that Vaubahn blueprints are now in the Nightwave shop since its debut a few years ago.